# Why Queue use other data structure like link list?

Tags: queue

Even if queue is already a data structure but still its implementation is done by array and link list.Why we can't use only queue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here. A Queue is largely a semantic description of the way you *use* an underlying structure (linked list, array, ...), with associated methods for those semantics. If you can more thoroughly explain what you're asking, we'll be better able to help.

Comment: A queue isn't a defined data structure. It's implementation can differ depending on the usage. Using a linked list is just one way to implement a queue (and one of the more efficient ones)